# Customize the design of Magento plugin

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, mageplaza

I am trying to change the UI of a Magento plugin. I am trying to override the template file of the plugin in my custom theme. The file is located at `app\code\Mageplaza\ConfigureGridView\view\frontend\templates\product\view\renderer.phtml` and I am trying to override it at `app\design\frontend\CustomVendor\us-packaging\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view\renderer.phtml`. But it is not working. I am able to override other template files of Magento. How can I override this template?

Comment: Did you check to make sure another extension did not override this template? Did you use template hints or test to make sure this was the correct template being displayed?

Comment: Yes. I used template hints. I also checked by renaming the file.

Comment: It is default mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to mirror the module's path to override it.

You said you're using `app\design\frontend\CustomVendor\us-packaging\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view\renderer.phtml` which will override a template from the catalog module.

The correct path is:

`app\design\frontend\CustomVendor\us-packaging\Mageplaza_ ConfigureGridView\templates\product\view\renderer.phtml`

Comment: That also didn't work

Comment: Sorry! It was my mistake, a space came in the folder name. It works.